# Splitting a string into multiple lines

Tags: python

So right now I have a program that adds text to a PDF and sends you a copy of the PDF which is the annotations. The only problem is that sometimes the text is too large and goes beyond what the PDF covers. I had a function in mind that splits the string by characters but I'm worried that it'll split a word and cause confusion. Is there a better alternative of splitting text into multiple sentences *without* splitting up a word across lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textwrap module provides some convenience functions, as well as TextWrapper, the class that does all the work. If you’re just wrapping or filling one or two text strings, the convenience functions should be good enough; otherwise, you should use an instance of TextWrapper for efficiency.

Or the inbuilt `wrap()` function. All of them have parameters not to break words.

Comment: Doing it manually by every n spaces won't provide a nice clean vertical edge as word lengths differ.